# Real Number System for Angles

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an analogue of the real number system that does the same thing for angles that the real number system does for points on a line? In other words, as the real numbers correspond one-to-one with points on a line, is there a system of numbers that corresponds one-to-one with points on a circle? It would be somewhat like the "ring of integers modulo *n*" but continuous. It might be hard to define as "less than" would have no meaning, but would it be enough to just use the quotient set of real numbers under the equivalence operator of differing by a multiple of 2π?

Comment: Also, if it is enough to just define an equivalence operator, is there a name for that system like "reals modulo 2π" or something?

Comment: The unit circle in the complex plane turns out to be isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$, the reals modulo the integers (Consider the map $t \mapsto e^{2 \pi it}$).

Comment: As @MaxthexPFarmer said, angles could be treated as reals modulo 2π = 360°. But note that it is better **not** to only use that ring when doing geometry. For example, the angle-at-centre theorem is that ∠AOB ≡ 2·∠ACB (mod 360°) for any triangle ABC with circumcentre O, but the angle-on-circumference theorem you get from that would be ∠ABC ≡ ∠ADC (mod 180°) for any cyclic quadrilateral ABCD, because you need to divide the first congruence by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can for example take $\{z\in\mathbb C| |z| = 1\}$, the unit circle on the complex plane. Their multiplication simulates summation of angles. They are isomorphic as (Lie) groups, and if you want to make a ring homomorphism, you have to specify what you mean by multiplying two angles together. In modern algebra, you can just abstractly formulate the quotient group (topologically as well if needed) $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with no reference to any other model at all. Note that as $\mathbb Z$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb R$, it's unlikely that you can make a ring out of the angles.